# Solution for graphing application events metrics in real time

Tags: metrics, graphite

We have an application that parses tweets and we want to see the activity in real time. We have tried several solution without success. Our main problems is that the graphing solution (example:graphite), needs a continious flow of metrics. When the db aggregates the metrics it's an average operation which is done, not a a sum.

We recently saw [cube from square](https://github.com/square/cube) which would fit our requirement but it's too new.

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in the last version of graphite:
http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config-carbon.html#storage-aggregation-conf

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you cannot feed graphite in realtime, for instance as soon as you discover a new tweet?

If that's the case, it looks like you can specify a unix timestamp when [updating graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/getting-your-data-into-graphite) `metric_path value timestamp\n` so you could pass in the time of discovery/publication/whatever, regardless of when you process it.

Comment: My main problem is graphite make average instead of sum of my values when aggreate the points. I think i can increase data retentions to fix this.

Comment: Ah yes, the resolution. The default is at 60-second resolution, you can change it to 10 seconds or even 1 second for near-realtime recording.